# If the Database is in Readonly mode how can we drop/remove those unused roles

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server, if the Database is in `Read_only` mode, can we drop/remove unused roles? Please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

If a database is in `READ_ONLY` mode, it is **completely** read-only. The read-only-ness is not limited to user data, but *anything* contained in the database. This means that both DML commands (ie, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`), and DDL commands (ie, `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`) are prohibited.

If the database is a read-only replica of an Availability Group, or a read-only log-shipping secondary, then you would need to drop the roles on the primary replica, and the normal data movement will replicate those changes to your read-only secondary. It is not possible for the secondary to have different security roles than the primary.

If your database is a stand-alone database that has been put into `READ_ONLY`, then you would need to set the database to read-write before dropping the unused role(s), then set the database back to read-only:

```
USE master
ALTER DATABASE [<MyReadOnlyDatabase>] SET READ_WRITE;
GO
USE [<MyReadOnlyDatabase>];
DROP ROLE [<OldUnusedRole>];
GO
USE master;
ALTER DATABASE [<MyReadOnlyDatabase>] SET READ_ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a change to a READ_ONLY database. You will have to set database to READ_WRITE before making any change.

Answer (score 0):

If the database is logshipped and your primary is not read_only but the secondary is, you would have to make the change on the primary for it to affect the secondary.  Answer by @SqlWorldWide is 100% correct.